# How to preserve newlines when using variables in here-strings

Tags: powershell

When running the following code:

```
  $txt = Get-Content file1.txt

    $a = @"
     -- file start --
     $txt
     -- file end --
    "@

   $a
```

All new lines are removed from the file's contents, but just running

```
$txt
```

prints out the file without stripping the new lines.

Any idea how to get it to work as desired using the here-string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pipe $txt to Out-String inside a sub-expression.

```
$a = @"
    -- file start --
    $($txt | Out-String)
    -- file end --
"@
```

Answer (score 14):

If you put an array in a string it will be expanded with `$OFS` (or a space if `$OFS` is `$null`) between the items. You can see the same effect with either

```
"$txt"
''+$txt
```

and a few others. You can set `` $OFS="`r`n" `` which would change the space with which they are joined to a line break.

You could also change the `Get-Content` at the start to either

```
$txt = Get-Content file1.txt | Out-String
$txt = [IO.File]::ReadAllText((Join-Path $pwd file1.txt))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that explained a lot about what's going on.